# Page jumps to top

Tags: plugin-development

I have a problem with a website, that I edited with Elementor. It keeps jumping to the top of the page after 1 sec. I have tried to move the navigation bar down, to see if that's what causes the problem, but it doesn't seem to be it. I have checked that there aren't any sticky features in the top section. I'm at a point where I don't have any more ideas, so I'll be happy for all inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: This feels like you've got a script on the page that takes a second to finish loading / initialising, and the last thing it does then is jump to the top. You could try looking at network and other timings in your browser's debug console to see if anything corresponds to the jump.

Comment: However this sounds like it's a problem with something Elementor. It might be worth asking them directly for support, as they'll have a better idea what's going on hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to a few different things, like some JavaScript conflict, an animation triggering the jump, or even a rogue plugin deciding to throw a party at the top of your page. So you'll have to do some troubleshooting to figure out what's causing it.

Check if there are any anchor links (`<a href="#...">`) near the top of your page that might be getting triggered. Also, look for any custom JavaScript that might be executing a scrollTo or similar function.

Elementor has all sorts of animations and effects, but sometimes they can get a bit finicky. Check your sections and widgets to see if there’s an animation that might be causing the jump.

Try deactivating all your plugins except Elementor and see if the problem persists. If the jump stops, reactivate your plugins one by one to find the culprit.

Check Elementor’s settings and look for anything that might be related to page scrolling or navigation. It’s a bit like looking for a needle in a haystack, but sometimes the smallest setting can be the cause.

Sometimes the theme itself can be the source of the problem. If you have a default theme like **Twenty Twenty-One**, try switching to it briefly and see if the issue persists.

Also, open your browser's developer tools and check the console for any errors. These can often give you clues about what's going wrong.I doubt you will find something there but who knows.